# ubuntu 17.10 cant login synclient command not found .xprofile

Tags: login

Today I updated from ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10, when trying to login an error appeared saying that in my .xprofile file, the synclient commands were not found:

synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient TapButton3=0
touchegg &

so I commented it out, and I could finally arrive to my loginpage, but now the keyboard and trackpad are completely unresponsive, I would really appreciate some help on how to solve this!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Small update: I connected an external mouse and it's working, however no keyboard input, any ideas? I don't have access to an external keyboard ..